# Could not establish handwhake with twitteR

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to use the twitteR package for R. To do so, I'm trying to establish a handshake with this code :

```
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=myKey, consumerSecret=mySecret, requestURL=reqURL, accessURL=accessURL, authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake()
```

This gets me this error :
`Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host`

Since I'm behind a proxy, I suspect it to cause troubles. However, I already configured R for that (I can download packages without troubles). As a consequence, I'm a little stuck.

Comment: What if you make it all `https`?

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you using the GitHub version (https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) or the old one from CRAN?

Comment: Since I downloaded from CRAN, I guess it's the old version. I'll try with the new one.

Comment: Looks like it's not specific to twitter, `install_github("httr")` also gives me the same message.